# Primefaces DataTable Lazy - Tabela não apresenta os registros

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou criando um datatable lazy, mas, apesar do load da classe estar carregando corretamente os registros, a tabela permanece vazia.

XHTML:

```html
<p:dataTable value="#{chamadoMB.chamados}" var="c" 
    paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
    rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" selectionMode="single" paginator="true" lazy="true" emptyMessage="Não há chamados concluídos">
    <p:column headerText="Prazo" sortBy="#{c.prazo}">
        <h:outputText value="#{c.prazo}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM"/>
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

ChamadoLazyList

```java
@Override
public List<Chamado> load(int start, int max, String string, SortOrder so, Map<String, String> map) {
    lista=new ChamadoDao().getChamados(start,max); 
    return lista; //<- Esta List está carregada corretamente
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolvido!
Faltava setar a quantidade total de registros na propriedade RowCount.

ChamadoLazyList

```java
public ChamadoLazyList(){
    this.setRowCount(new ChamadoDao().getQtChamados());
}
```